# how to set a custom color for a specific word like IDE

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

i wanna create a text field and when a user type a word it will check and if it equals to "test" for example, test's color will changes to red and so on
im using c++builder, so how can it be done?

Comment: Consider narrowing your question down and focusing on a specific problem you're having. At the moment, you're simply asking us to do work for you, as opposed to asking for help with an issue you've run into. Show us what you've done and what's not working, and we can help you make that portion work.

Comment: @MikePrecup im not asking you to do my work, i just need a help like a article about that, not just a code

Comment: It depends on the GUI framework (or console functionality). Maybe with c++builder some specific GUI framework is overwhelmingly most likely, so that it goes without saying? Still it would be good to mention it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, but asking for off-site links is [off topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `TRichEdit` for that.  You can use its `SelStart` and `SelLength` properties to select the word and then use its `SelAttributes->Color` property to change the word's font color (or use the Win32 API equivalents).  Refer to the following article for some details about how to implement a "syntax highlighter" with `TRichEdit`:

[Faster rich edit syntax highlighting](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol3/9910/Faster_rich_edit_syntax_highlighting.htm)